# CSS file not generating using node-sass in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, sass, node-sass

I am using `node-sass` to convert `sass` files to `css` but somehow its not creating css file in a folder. Please help me out with what I am doing wrong with the code.

My Folder structure is like -

[image: Folder Img]

And I have a `main.scss` file in `css` folder.

My `index.js` code is -

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sass = require('node-sass');

sass.render({
  file: './css/main.scss',
  outFile: './css/main.css',
}, function(err, result) { 
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Though no error is thrown in the console but the css file is also not generating in `CSS` folder. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

FYI - Here is the result output in console.

[image: Output Img]

**EDIT 1**

I changed the code of index.js file to the following but still not working -

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sass = require('node-sass');

sass.render({
  file: './css/main.scss',
  outFile: 'css',
}, function(err, result) { 
    if(err)
        throw err;
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/css/', 'main.css', function(err){
        if(!err){
          //file written on disk
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Checkout the node-sass docs for outFile](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#outfile):

> Specify the intended location of the output file. Strongly recommended when outputting source maps so that they can properly refer back to their intended files.
>
> **Attention** enabling this option will not write the file on disk for you, it's for internal reference purpose only (to generate the map for example).

So you need to manually write the output to disk:

```
sass.render({
    ...
    outFile: yourPathTotheFile,
  }, function(error, result) { // node-style callback from v3.0.0 onwards
    if(!error){
      // No errors during the compilation, write this result on the disk
      fs.writeFile(yourPathTotheFile, result.css, function(err){
        if(!err){
          //file written on disk
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are calling the fs.writeFile method with the wrong params. It takes path to file, file contents, callback, but you gave it path to file, filename, callback.

Comment: Ahh okk..please add this to your answer

Comment: The answer already shows you this. See where it says result.css? That's all you need to do. Instead you put 'main.css'.

Comment: BTW when I changed the code to `fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/css/main.css', result, function(err){
        if(!err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      });`  this, main.css is generating but with css `[object Object]`

Comment: Again, follow the example in my answer. result.css. RESULT.CSS

Comment: I just want to add that I was confused with `result.css`. I thought this was referring to a *file* called `result.css`. This is actually the `css` key of the `result` object, so `result.css` is exactly how it should appear. No spaces. Thanks for the help @Nesh